# Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '12,11''

Tags: php, mysql

My ***POST form*** sends a value `&messages=12,11`

I get it using: `$messages = $ep->remove($_POST["messages"]);`

And my **SQL** string is:

```
$query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageID IN ('".$messages."') AND accountID=:accountID");
$query->execute([':accountID' => $accountID]);
```

And the error appears....

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '12,11'' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.xxx/xx/xxx/xx/xxxx/messages.php:17
```

This code deletes ***multiple*** messages from the database. But don't works for me. Any fix?

Comment: Can you share the corresponding database value you are trying to delete?

Comment: Remove quotes `''`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation marks:

```
$query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageID IN (".$messages.") AND accountID=:accountID");
```

Otherwise the value you're sending is `12,11` (which isn't a number as per your database definition), as opposed to `12` and `11`, which are both numbers.

Finally, this particular query structure is open to SQL injection. You may want to either sanitise the `$messages` variable (since it can only include numbers), or create a prepared statement.

For this example, sanitising could work as follows:

```
$messages = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]/', '', $messages);
//Removes all characters besides numbers and commas
```

You could also ensure that the list of numeric message IDs always matches the following regex pattern:

```
$\d+(?:,\d+)*$
```

That is, the parameter should always be some number, followed by an optional quantity of `,\d+` terms

```
if (!preg_match("/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/", $messages)) {
    // throw an exception, you are being injected
}
```

Comment: Oh absolutely, but neither is his original query. I added a warning to my answer.

Comment: @Aspoky I added an example on how to sanitise.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the other answer, here is a way to properly prepare all the values

```
$array = explode(',', '1,2,3,4,5,6');

$keys = preg_replace('/(.+)/', ':v\1', array_keys($array));
print_r($keys);

$sql = "DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageID IN ( ".implode(',', $keys)." ) AND accountID=:accountID";
print_r($sql);

$params = array_combine($keys,$array);
$params['accountID'] = 'foo';

print_r($params);

//$stmt->execute($params);
```

Output

```
//print_r($keys);
Array
(
    [0] => :v0
    [1] => :v1
    [2] => :v2
    [3] => :v3
    [4] => :v4
    [5] => :v5
)

//print_r($sql);
DELETE FROM messages WHERE messageID IN ( :v0,:v1,:v2,:v3,:v4,:v5 ) AND accountID=:accountID

//print_r($params);
Array
(
    [:v0] => 1
    [:v1] => 2
    [:v2] => 3
    [:v3] => 4
    [:v4] => 5
    [:v5] => 6
    [accountID] => foo
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c88e54150196120793ef4e1bd4179548501ef56)

It was way too much for a comment.

Basically it takes the keys and using preg replace we can take the sequential number and add a string to it (placeholders have to start with a alpha). Technically the `:` in the array for execute is optional.

Then we can put that into the query, as it's all generated by PHP because the keys are made from explode. If you have keys from POST, don't use those instead use `array_keys(array_values($array))` array values will make the array numerically indexed, then you use those keys.

Next using array combine we can merge those keys back into the original values and put that array into `execute`

**In this case** You can do it just with a regex, but I wanted to show something that was useful for more complex cases of IN.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I experienced this broader error due to blindly copying one of my earlier [bind_param](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) statements for re-use in another query further down in my project. I were passing in a string variable in a position where `bind_param` were expecting a numerical float value (`d`).

A quick tweak to that particular query's `bind_param` `$types` fixed this issue for me when it started expecting a string (`s`) as intended.